# Populating a pandas dataframe with a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to populate a pandas dataframe with a string from numpy array

```
t = zeros((10, 3))

v = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10), columns=['a', 'b','c'])
```

Let's say columns 'a' and 'b' are floats and column 'c' should be a string

```
t[i] = fun(x)

v.iloc[i, 0:3] = t[0, 0], t[0, 1], t[0, 2]

# t[0, 0], t[0, 1] are floats and t[0, 2] is a string.
```

I'm trying to do this within a for loop, but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

Comment: it looks like the values for you `df` will just be `t`

Comment: assuming `t` is a numpy array, it cannot have floats and strings in same array.  by definition numpy array has to have all values of same type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@yulGM's comment is the answer. The issue is that numpy array has to have all elements of the same type, so I simply made a second array just for strings. This can also be solved with dictionaries and in other ways.